# How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-devtools

So apparently because of the recent scams, the developer tools are exploited by people to post spam and even used to "hack" accounts. Facebook has blocked the developer tools, and I can't even use the console.

[image]

How did they do that?? [One Stack Overflow post claimed it is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/disable-developer-tools), but Facebook has proven them wrong.

Just go to Facebook and open up the developer tools, type one character into the console, and this warning pops up. No matter what you put in, it will not get executed.

How is this possible?

They even blocked auto-complete in the console:

[image]

Comment: Just for fun : console.log = function() {}

Comment: Did you find solution for how they blocked auto complete feature in console

Comment: @AkshayHegde It was a side effect caused by blocking any code execution from the devtools.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 can you please share code

Comment: just fyi, it's not blocked in chrome any more.

Comment: it's not blocked anymore, chrome etc has fixed the ability for developers to do this.

Answer (score 2535, accepted):

I'm a security engineer at Facebook and this is my fault. We're testing this for some users to see if it can slow down some attacks where users are tricked into pasting (malicious) JavaScript code into the browser console.

Just to be clear: trying to block hackers client-side is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/disable-developer-tools) in general;
this is to protect against a [specific social engineering attack](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=956977232793).

If you ended up in the test group and are annoyed by this, sorry.
I tried to make the old opt-out page (now [help page](https://www.facebook.com/selfxss))  as simple as possible while still being scary enough to stop at least *some* of the victims.

The actual code is pretty similar to [@joeldixon66's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21692733); ours is a little more complicated for no good reason.

Chrome wraps all console code in

```
with ((console && console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
  <code goes here>
}
```

... so the site redefines `console._commandLineAPI` to throw:

```
Object.defineProperty(console, '_commandLineAPI',
   { get : function() { throw 'Nooo!' } })
```

This is [not quite enough (try it!)](http://escape.alf.nu/20), but that's the
main trick.

---

Epilogue: The Chrome team decided that defeating the console from user-side JS was a bug and [fixed the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=349993), rendering this technique invalid. Afterwards, additional protection was added to [protect users from self-xss](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345205#c21).

Comment: Chrome did make an update but this guy made a fix again: http://kspace.in/blog/2014/06/21/revisiting-disable-javascript-execution-from-console/

Comment: @Alf, your opt-out page now shows the help page without any possibility to turn down this protection off.

Comment: Please don't break developer tools because of some users' stupidity. "Solutions" like this make me burn with rage of a million suns.

Comment: @Alf, I want disable browser debug console such as Facebook, but your code not works. Google Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)

Comment: @LONGMAN The Chrome team [has fixed it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345205).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 fixed? I have last chrome but on facebook anyway not works console. I want get same result

Comment: I think Google needs to release a "Safe" version of Chrome, no DevTools, and force anyone on automatic updates to switch to this version just once. Any developer that actually notices the difference and needs the DevTools should download the "scary" version. In fact, label them as "Scary" and "Safe" directly on the download page and deter Darwinians from causing themselves harm by explicitly stating that "You are likely here because a social engineering attack told you to download the Scary version; please do not do this." God bless you FB devs for being so creative!

Comment: I understand the Chrome team has fixed the 'broken console' issue, but how come Facebook is still able to 'inject' a message into the console header? You still see that "warning" message when you are on Facebook and open the console.  Isnt that a bug? i didnt see that mentioned in the bug reports.

Comment: @n00b That warning message is just a `console.log`.

Comment: @Alf Do you have any reliable and efficient reference to some code on how facebook detects when the inspector is opened? Not to disable it, but to detect it open. There are some hacks out there, but I would like something that works reliably and efficiently.

Comment: Disabling console by javascript is a HELL of a BUG!

Comment: Can you explane how this compromise facebook account or let somebody to your account?

Comment: @RogerWayne https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/dont-be-a-self-xss-victim/10152054702905766/

Comment: ...and https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=210&v=XrzSaohJ0a8 is more interesting

Comment: @mjwatts Don't understand.. "Press J, Press Ctrl V" From where that code come from?

Comment: The baddies provide the code it could be anything. They ask you to open developer tools (ctrl + v), navigate to console then paste the code (ctrl + v). The code executes. The code will be something that runs a command on the page perhaps. Like send message to all friends, I don’t know - I haven’t seen an example of the code up close.

Comment: Great write-up. This exploit reminds me of this oldie but goodie.

https://i.imgur.com/uvou947.gif

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : DevTools could be a browser plugin I suppose, which people would need to explicitly install.

Comment: love the "ours is a little more complicated for no good reason" comment, awesome honesty there.

Comment: It seems the “specific social engineering attack” link is dead

Comment: So this is Chrome's fault? I just want to block people from my business page, without them having to LIKE it first. I used to be able to Inspect and inject the FB ID over another account that actually did LIKE my business. Could you please place such a feature to find anyone and block from a business page? I am not the only one asking for this.

Comment: This code is not working. I tried but no success

Answer (score 99):

I located the Facebook's console buster script using Chrome developer tools. Here is the script with minor changes for readability. I have removed the bits that I could not understand:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "console", {
    value: console,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
});

var i = 0;
function showWarningAndThrow() {
    if (!i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("%cWarning message", "font: 2em sans-serif; color: yellow; background-color: red;");
        }, 1);
        i = 1;
    }
    throw "Console is disabled";
}

var l, n = {
        set: function (o) {
            l = o;
        },
        get: function () {
            showWarningAndThrow();
            return l;
        }
    };
Object.defineProperty(console, "_commandLineAPI", n);
Object.defineProperty(console, "__commandLineAPI", n);
```

With this, the console auto-complete fails silently while statements typed in console will fail to execute (the exception will be logged).

References:

- [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)
- [Chrome's console.log function (for tips on formatting output)](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject_object)

Answer (score 49):

I couldn't get it to trigger that on any page. A more robust version of this would do it:

```
window.console.log = function(){
    console.error('The developer console is temp...');
    window.console.log = function() {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log('test');
```

To style the output: [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017382/3189029)

**Edit** Thinking [@joeldixon66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21692733/282110) has the right idea: [Disable JavaScript execution from console «  ::: KSpace :::](http://kspace.in/blog/2013/02/22/disable-javascript-execution-from-console/)

Comment: cool one but still then override the same `window.console.log = function(){//empty}` and use console.log

Answer (score 34):

Besides redefining `console._commandLineAPI`,
there are some other ways to break into InjectedScriptHost on WebKit browsers, to prevent or alter the evaluation of expressions entered into the developer's console.

**Edit:**

Chrome has fixed this in a past release. *- which must have been before February 2015, as I created the gist at that time*

So here's another possibility. This time we hook in, a level above, directly into `InjectedScript` rather than `InjectedScriptHost` as opposed to the prior version.

Which is kind of nice, as you can directly monkey patch `InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap` instead of having to rely on `InjectedScriptHost.evaluate` as that gives you more fine-grained control over what should happen.

Another pretty interesting thing is, that we can intercept the internal result when an expression is evaluated and *return that* to the user instead of the normal behavior.

Here is the code, that does exactly that, return the internal result when a user evaluates something in the console.

```
var is;
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,"_lastResult",{
   get:function(){
       return this._lR;
   },
   set:function(v){
       if (typeof this._commandLineAPIImpl=="object") is=this;
       this._lR=v;
   }
});
setTimeout(function(){
   var ev=is._evaluateAndWrap;
   is._evaluateAndWrap=function(){
       var res=ev.apply(is,arguments);
       console.log();
       if (arguments[2]==="completion") {
           //This is the path you end up when a user types in the console and autocompletion get's evaluated

           //Chrome expects a wrapped result to be returned from evaluateAndWrap.
           //You can use `ev` to generate an object yourself.
           //In case of the autocompletion chrome exptects an wrapped object with the properties that can be autocompleted. e.g.;
           //{iGetAutoCompleted: true}
           //You would then go and return that object wrapped, like
           //return ev.call (is, '', '({test:true})', 'completion', true, false, true);
           //Would make `test` pop up for every autocompletion.
           //Note that syntax as well as every Object.prototype property get's added to that list later,
           //so you won't be able to exclude things like `while` from the autocompletion list,
           //unless you wou'd find a way to rewrite the getCompletions function.
           //
           return res; //Return the autocompletion result. If you want to break that, return nothing or an empty object
       } else {
           //This is the path where you end up when a user actually presses enter to evaluate an expression.
           //In order to return anything as normal evaluation output, you have to return a wrapped object.

           //In this case, we want to return the generated remote object. 
           //Since this is already a wrapped object it would be converted if we directly return it. Hence,
           //`return result` would actually replicate the very normal behaviour as the result is converted.
           //to output what's actually in the remote object, we have to stringify it and `evaluateAndWrap` that object again.`
           //This is quite interesting;
           return ev.call (is, null, '(' + JSON.stringify (res) + ')', "console", true, false, true)
       }
   };
},0);
```

*It's a bit verbose, but I thought I put some comments into it*

So normally, if a user, for example, evaluates `[1,2,3,4]` you'd expect the following output:

[image]

After monkeypatching `InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap` evaluating the very same expression, gives the following output:

[image]

As you see the little-left arrow, indicating output, is still there, but this time we get an object. Where the result of the expression, the array `[1,2,3,4]` is represented as an object with all its properties described.

I recommend trying to evaluate this and that expression, including those that generate errors. It's quite interesting.

Additionally, take a look at the `is` *- `InjectedScriptHost` -* object. It provides some methods to play with and get a bit of insight into the internals of the inspector.

Of course, you could intercept all that information and still return the original result to the user.

Just replace the return statement in the else path by a `console.log (res)` following a `return res`. Then you'd end up with the following.

[image]

*End of Edit*

---

This is the prior version which was fixed by Google. Hence not a possible way anymore.

<s>One of it is hooking into `Function.prototype.call`</s>

Chrome evaluates the entered expression by `call`ing its eval function with `InjectedScriptHost` as `thisArg`

`var result = evalFunction.call(object, expression);`

Given this, you can listen for the `thisArg` of `call` being `evaluate` and get a reference to the first argument (`InjectedScriptHost`)

```
if (window.URL) {
    var ish, _call = Function.prototype.call;
    Function.prototype.call = function () { //Could be wrapped in a setter for _commandLineAPI, to redefine only when the user started typing.
        if (arguments.length > 0 && this.name === "evaluate" && arguments [0].constructor.name === "InjectedScriptHost") { //If thisArg is the evaluate function and the arg0 is the ISH
            ish = arguments[0];
            ish.evaluate = function (e) { //Redefine the evaluation behaviour
                throw new Error ('Rejected evaluation of: \n\'' + e.split ('\n').slice(1,-1).join ("\n") + '\'');
            };
            Function.prototype.call = _call; //Reset the Function.prototype.call
            return _call.apply(this, arguments);  
        }
    };
}
```

You could e.g. throw an error, that the evaluation was rejected.

[image]

<sub>Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/jW7jp/show) where the entered expression gets passed to a CoffeeScript compiler before passing it to the `evaluate` function.</sub>

Answer (score 29):

Netflix also implements this feature

```
(function() {
    try {
        var $_console$$ = console;
        Object.defineProperty(window, "console", {
            get: function() {
                if ($_console$$._commandLineAPI)
                    throw "Sorry, for security reasons, the script console is deactivated on netflix.com";
                return $_console$$
            },
            set: function($val$$) {
                $_console$$ = $val$$
            }
        })
    } catch ($ignore$$) {
    }
})();
```

They just override `console._commandLineAPI` to throw security error.

Answer (score 27):

This is actually possible since Facebook was able to do it.
Well, not the actual web developer tools but the execution of Javascript in console.

See this: [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/)

This really wont do much though since there are other ways to bypass this type of client-side security.

When you say it is client-side, it happens outside the control of the server, so there is not much you can do about it. If you are asking why Facebook still does this, this is not really for security but to protect normal users that do not know javascript from running code (that they don't know how to read) into the console. This is common for sites that promise auto-liker service or other Facebook functionality bots after you do what they ask you to do, where in most cases, they give you a snip of javascript to run in console.

If you don't have as much users as Facebook, then I don't think there's any need to do what Facebook is doing.

Even if you disable Javascript in console, running javascript via address bar is still possible.

[image]

[image]

and if the browser disables javascript at address bar, (When you paste code to the address bar in Google Chrome, it deletes the phrase 'javascript:') pasting javascript into one of the links via inspect element is still possible.

**Inspect the anchor:**

[image]

**Paste code in href:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Bottom line is server-side validation and security should be first, then do client-side after.

Answer (score 14):

Chrome changed a lot since the times facebook could disable console...

As per March 2017 this doesn't work anymore.

Best you can do is disable some of the console functions, example:

```
if(!window.console) window.console = {};
var methods = ["log", "debug", "warn", "info", "dir", "dirxml", "trace", "profile"];
for(var i=0;i<methods.length;i++){
    console[methods[i]] = function(){};
}
```

Answer (score 13):

My simple way, but it can help for further variations on this subject.
List all methods and alter them to useless.

```
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(console).filter(function(property) {
     return typeof console[property] == 'function';
  }).forEach(function (verb) {
     console[verb] =function(){return 'Sorry, for security reasons...';};
  });
```

However, a better approach is to disable the developer tool from being opened in any meaningful way

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(console).filter(function(property) {
        return typeof console[property] == 'function';
    }).forEach(function (verb) {
        console[verb] =function(){return 'Sorry, for security reasons...';};
    });
    window.addEventListener('devtools-opened', ()=>{
        // do some extra code if needed or ...
        // maybe even delete the page, I still like to add redirect just in case
        window.location.href+="#";
        window.document.head.innerHTML="";
        window.document.body.innerHTML="devtools, page is now cleared";
    });
    window.addEventListener('devtools-closed', ()=>{
        // do some extra code if needed
    });
    let verifyConsole = () => {
        var before = new Date().getTime();
        debugger;
        var after = new Date().getTime();
        if (after - before > 100) { // user had to resume the script manually via opened dev tools 
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('devtools-opened'));
        }else{
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('devtools-closed'));
        }
        setTimeout(verifyConsole, 100);
    }
    verifyConsole();        
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

Internally devtools injects an IIFE named `getCompletions` into the page, called when a key is pressed inside the Devtools console.

Looking at the [source of that function](https://gist.github.com/samdenty/72b29483131bf9c13977fce758b57b26), it uses a few global functions which can be overwritten.

By using the [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) constructor it's possible to get the call stack, which will include `getCompletions` when called by Devtools.

---

**Example:**

```js
const disableDevtools = callback => {
  const original = Object.getPrototypeOf;

  Object.getPrototypeOf = (...args) => {
    if (Error().stack.includes("getCompletions")) callback();
    return original(...args);
  };
};

disableDevtools(() => {
  console.error("devtools has been disabled");

  while (1);
});
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, but it also crashes the page.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Only way (I've found) to suppress further user input

Comment: I wonder if you can throw an error instead of using an infinite loop. Edit: Tested, does not work.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 it's in a try catch block. You could probably override the functions above the block, but it would only prevent auto completion (not evaluation)

Comment: sadly does not work. I can still use dev tools by pressing -> triple dot on chrome -> more tools ->developer tools..

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple way here:
`window.console = function () {}`

Answer (score 0):

an simple solution!

```
setInterval(()=>console.clear(),1500);
```

Comment: How does this disable the `console.log()`?

Comment: `console.log()` no longer matters when console constantly is cleaned up :)

Comment: this is a bad idea. hacker can trace from their terminal and see all the logs.

Comment: and if you flag Preserve Logs, console.clear() does nothing :P

Answer (score 0):

I would go along the way of:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', {
  get: function() {

  },
  set: function() {

  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In Firefox it dosen't do that, since Firefox is a developer browser, I think since the command `WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprecated in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER` and the error `Referrer Policy: Less restricted policies, including ‘no-referrer-when-downgrade’, ‘origin-when-cross-origin’ and ‘unsafe-url’, will be ignored soon for the cross-site request: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yS/r/XDDAHSZfaR6.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz`.

Answer (score -2):

**This is not a security measure for weak code to be left unattended. Always get a permanent solution to weak code and secure your websites properly before implementing this strategy**

The best tool by far according to my knowledge would be to add multiple javascript files that simply changes the integrity of the page back to normal by refreshing or replacing content. Disabling this developer tool would not be the greatest idea since bypassing is always in question since the code is part of the browser and not a server rendering, thus it could be cracked.

Should you have `js file one` checking for `<element>` changes on important elements and `js file two` and `js file three` checking that this file exists per period you will have full integrity restore on the page within the period.

Lets take an example of the 4 files and show you what I mean.

**index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head id="mainhead">
   <script src="ks.js" id="ksjs"></script>
   <script src="mainfile.js" id="mainjs"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" id="style">
   <meta id="meta1" name="description" content="Proper mitigation against script kiddies via Javascript" >
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1 id="heading" name="dontdel" value="2">Delete this from console and it will refresh. If you change the name attribute in this it will also refresh. This is mitigating an attack on attribute change via console to exploit vulnerabilities. You can even try and change the value attribute from 2 to anything you like. If This script says it is 2 it should be 2 or it will refresh. </h1>
   <h3>Deleting this wont refresh the page due to it having no integrity check on it</h3>

   <p>You can also add this type of error checking on meta tags and add one script out of the head tag to check for changes in the head tag. You can add many js files to ensure an attacker cannot delete all in the second it takes to refresh. Be creative and make this your own as your website needs it. 
   </p>

   <p>This is not the end of it since we can still enter any tag to load anything from everywhere (Dependent on headers etc) but we want to prevent the important ones like an override in meta tags that load headers. The console is designed to edit html but that could add potential html that is dangerous. You should not be able to enter any meta tags into this document unless it is as specified by the ks.js file as permissable. <br>This is not only possible with meta tags but you can do this for important tags like input and script. This is not a replacement for headers!!! Add your headers aswell and protect them with this method.</p>
   </body>
   <script src="ps.js" id="psjs"></script>
   </html>
```

**mainfile.js**

```
   setInterval(function() {
   // check for existence of other scripts. This part will go in all other files to check for this file aswell. 
   var ksExists = document.getElementById("ksjs"); 
   if(ksExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};

   var psExists = document.getElementById("psjs");
   if(psExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};

   var styleExists = document.getElementById("style");
   if(styleExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};


   }, 1 * 1000); // 1 * 1000 milsec
```

**ps.js**

```
   /*This script checks if mainjs exists as an element. If main js is not existent as an id in the html file reload!You can add this to all js files to ensure that your page integrity is perfect every second. If the page integrity is bad it reloads the page automatically and the process is restarted. This will blind an attacker as he has one second to disable every javascript file in your system which is impossible.

   */

   setInterval(function() {
   // check for existence of other scripts. This part will go in all other files to check for this file aswell. 
   var mainExists = document.getElementById("mainjs"); 
   if(mainExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};

   //check that heading with id exists and name tag is dontdel.
   var headingExists = document.getElementById("heading"); 
   if(headingExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};
   var integrityHeading = headingExists.getAttribute('name');
   if(integrityHeading == 'dontdel') {
   }else{ location.reload();};
   var integrity2Heading = headingExists.getAttribute('value');
   if(integrity2Heading == '2') {
   }else{ location.reload();};
   //check that all meta tags stay there
   var meta1Exists = document.getElementById("meta1"); 
   if(meta1Exists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};

   var headExists = document.getElementById("mainhead"); 
   if(headExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};

   }, 1 * 1000); // 1 * 1000 milsec
```

**ks.js**

```
   /*This script checks if mainjs exists as an element. If main js is not existent as an id in the html file reload! You can add this to all js files to ensure that your page integrity is perfect every second. If the page integrity is bad it reloads the page automatically and the process is restarted. This will blind an attacker as he has one second to disable every javascript file in your system which is impossible.

   */

   setInterval(function() {
   // check for existence of other scripts. This part will go in all other files to check for this file aswell. 
   var mainExists = document.getElementById("mainjs"); 
   if(mainExists) {
   }else{ location.reload();};
   //Check meta tag 1 for content changes. meta1 will always be 0. This you do for each meta on the page to ensure content credibility. No one will change a meta and get away with it. Addition of a meta in spot 10, say a meta after the id="meta10" should also be covered as below.
   var x = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];
   var p = x.getAttribute("name");
   var s = x.getAttribute("content");
   if (p != 'description') {
   location.reload();
   }
   if ( s != 'Proper mitigation against script kiddies via Javascript') {
   location.reload();
   }
   // This will prevent a meta tag after this meta tag @ id="meta1". This prevents new meta tags from being added to your pages. This can be used for scripts or any tag you feel is needed to do integrity check on like inputs and scripts. (Yet again. It is not a replacement for headers to be added. Add your headers aswell!)
   var lastMeta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[1];
   if (lastMeta) {
   location.reload();
   }
   }, 1 * 1000); // 1 * 1000 milsec
```

**style.css**

Now this is just to show it works on all files and tags aswell

```
   #heading {
   background-color:red;
   }
```

If you put all these files together and build the example you will see the function of this measure. This will prevent some unforseen injections should you implement it correctly on all important elements in your index file especially when working with PHP.

Why I chose reload instead of change back to normal value per attribute is the fact that some attackers could have another part of the website already configured and ready and it lessens code amount. The reload will remove all the attacker's hard work and he will probably go play somewhere easier.

Another note: **This could become a lot of code so keep it clean and make sure to add definitions to where they belong to make edits easy in future. Also set the seconds to your preferred amount as 1 second intervals on large pages could have drastic effects on older computers your visitors might be using**