# javascript getting the execution environment

Tags: javascript

I need to get the execution environment of JS code. if it is a console or if it browser. How should I approach this?

for instance:

```
if(exec_type() == 'browser')
{
 // do something
}
```

What is the purpose of it? I want to add some functionality if the code is not run from a console such as firebug, and to disable them when it is run from console environment.

Comment: This might be relevant, and might lead you to what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools/21692733#21692733

Comment: There's no easy, x-way of doing this. If you could list the specific consoles you're targeting, it might be possible to give you parameters to check for, to see if you're in *that specific environment*.

Comment: you would have to use quirky method to do it this way, ex: (function(){ return arguments.callee.caller }()), you'de be better off passing a flag to your code.

Comment: What is "*a console*"??? The node.js prompt?

Comment: Can you please re-word this? You use the term `console` too much for this to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function:

```
function isInWindow() {
  return this === window;
}
```

It will return true if script is running in window namespace (browser).

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZU4qp/)

Comment: If I run this code in a JS console it returns `true`. What does this help you identify exactly? For instance, where will this function return `false`?

Comment: @Jasper If you run this in console attached to the window it will return you `true`. If you will run this under, say, node.js it will return you `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these functions will help you.

```
function isInWindow(){
  if(typeof window === "object"){
    return true;  
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
function isInNode(){
  if(typeof global === "object"){
    return true;  
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(isInWindow); // true, if in browser
console.log(isInNode);  // true, if in node.js
```

Here is [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/wigopaw/edit?js,console)