# Restrict access to 'style' property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype, ecmascript-5

I'm starting to develop a small JavaScript library and I want to make styling of HTML elements possible only through my API (because for some reason I need to have full control over styling).

So I want to make `style` property inaccessible (my API will access it through my `style` alias - not an ideal solution, but for other libraries like jQuery it will do the trick).

If I write this (inspired by [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools)):

```
var box = document.getElementById('someElementId');
Object.defineProperty(box, 'style', {
    get: function() {
        throw 'you cant access style property';
    }
});
box.style.color = 'red';
```

it works for `box` element only.

Is it possible to do this for all (existing and future) elements in Webkit, Firefox, and IE9+?

I've also tried this:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement, 'style', {...
```

but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

As @Teemu suggested I can write `HTMLElement.prototype` instead of `HTMLElement`, and it works fine in FF and IE, but not in Chrome. And it looks like a [Chrome bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prototype-scriptaculous/h9lDsl0FcP4). Sadly...

**Edit2 - why do I need it**

The main goal of a library I want to develop is to allow writing styles like:

```
element.setWidth('parent.width / 2 - 10');
```

In this case `element`'s width should react on each changing of the `parent`'s width.
But since `onresize` event is available only for `window` object ([this article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) seems to be obsolete),
the only way I can "listen" modifying `.style.width` property is to perform my own API for styling.
And I want to restrict (or at least show warning) direct `style` modifying because it will break the elements' behavior.

Comment: Just curious, if style is inaccessible, how will your API set it?

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'style', {...})` would do the trick. How you'll set the `style` in your API then, I don't know...

Comment: @Teemu, @Gary I think of something like this: `box._css = box.style;` (before restricting), and then access to `._css` property. Of cource this is not a panacea, but perhaps it will work for other libraries like jQuery

Comment: @Teemu your solution doesn't work, unfortunately (

Comment: @Zub [How is that](http://jsfiddle.net/u96np/)? - I see, it doesn't work in Chrome, works fine in IE and FF though.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, it works in FF and IE, but not Chrome (33.0.1750.117 - Linux)

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug? DOM Level 2 defines "style" as a readonly **attribute** — http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-htmlelementcss Just because some browsers choose to implement style as getter/setter on `HTMLElement.prototype` and others — as direct property of an element object (`document.createElement('p').hasOwnProperty('style') === true` in Chrome) doesn't mean that it's a bug. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: @kangax thank you for such deep explanation! So if Chrome implements `style` as direct property of an element, do I have to perform `Object.defineProperty` for **each** element on a page, or there is an easier way to disable styling?

Comment: But… why? Why do you want to restrict access to anything?

Comment: @Zub Open documentation file. Put in a big, bold, red "DO NOT USE STYLE ATTRIBUTE" warning. :P

Comment: @bjb568 Yeah, I definitely have to do it as well :D

Comment: @Zub Yeah, you'd need to seal each element individually. Or overwrite all of the methods (`createElement`, `getElementById`, etc.) that return an element to return already sealed element. But that's an even bigger can of worms, so I don't suggest you even go there.

Comment: @kangax Sadly. It looks like I have to follow bjb568's recommendation :) Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you can tell that restricting access to the style property is probably not such a good route. But I understand from your question that your reason from trying to go this route is that the resize event only fires for the window object.

If you would be able to circumvent the whole restricting issue with a resize event on just any element, than may I suggest you look into Ben Alman's [jQuery resize event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) plugin. I'm not sure whether you want to develop with jQuery, but even if you don't it may be worth it to read that plugin's code. Basically, what it does is make a hashtable of listeners mapped to the element(s) they are listening on and then in a polling loop (with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)) check the size of the elements in that map. If it has changed during the interval (250ms by default) it triggers the listeners itself. It works reasonably well. That specific plugin hooks into jQuery's event system, but you could just make your own addResizeEvent function or something to that effect.

Edit: Upon re-reading your question it dawns on me that it looks like you are trying to develop some mechanism to deal with the downsides of the CSS box model, e.g. that when you give an element 5px padding and a width of 50% it will end up being 10 pixels wider than half the parent container. Consider [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, I thought about `setInterval`. But there is a problem with this approach. Lets say we have a situation where B-element's width depends on A-element's width. We change A width, and in 100ms we want to get B width. Since `setInterval` callback is being called with 250ms interval, we can't say whether B width has been updated by this time, or not. Sometimes we will get an old value, and sometimes new one. I bet that this "sometimes" stuff drives every programmer crazy :) That's why I decided not to use `setInterval` in this.

Comment: Yes, if you would use setInterval, the `setWidth()` call in your API would need to just add an operation to some stack and on the polling loop you would need to process them in order. But what about `box-sizing: border-box`? It seems it can fix most of the situations where you would need to do things like `setWidth(parent.width / 2 -10)`.

Comment: In case of `parent.width / 2 -10` it can. But if we have more complicated expression, e.g. `parent.width - #someEl.height + #someOtherEl.paddingLeft + 50`, it won't do the trick. Of course this is contrived example, but it demonstrates the flexibility of this kind of expressions

Comment: What is your intention with the API? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to create layout library that allows to write the above expressions. I wanted to forbid accessing to `style` attribute because as I mentioned it might break the elements behavior. But since I can't do it cross-browser, I will probably give up the idea with forbidding `style`, and search other ways to keep elements behavior in order. And I will accept your answer because I appreciate your effort. Thank you very much for your help :)