# How to disable javascript console?

Tags: javascript, console

I have a problem with my webpage. If my users use the console they can cheat in my JS game, and then save to the server.

Can I send a redirect to the login page if they try to execute anything from console?

Comment: Dedicated hackers will still be able to cheat at your game by faking the HTTP request from outside the browser (using curl or whatever other tool). Additionally, while there are some tricks out there that break consoles, they are annoying for users and will not work on every browser or browser version

Comment: "The client is in the hands of the enemy" You need to figure out how to detect cheating at the server side. Fundamentally, there's nothing you can do to prevent the client being tampered.

Comment: but once ago i tryed that: http://kspace.in/blog/2013/02/22/disable-javascript-execution-from-console/ 

From that website and it works! Why dosen't work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post for more information about the question you're asking - you may be a little off in your understanding of the situation:

[How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools)