# How did Facebook change the font of Javascript console output?

Tags: javascript, browser

Example screenshot from the JavaScript console (Google Chrome 35, Win7) on a Facebook page:

[image: Example screenshot]

How is this done? Is there a way to inspect/debug the console?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api

Comment: When does that happen? I opened the JS console on Mac Chrome 36 while at facebook.com, I didn't see it.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Console API Reference:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css

Nice example of using the `console.log`:

```
console.log("%cUser %s has %d points", "color:orange; background:blue; font-size: 16pt", 'User', 100);
```

Just paste it into the console :)