# Prevent console.log to display the reference

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

On various websites you can discover messages (mostly for developers) when you open the Developer Tools. For instance on Facebook you get this message:

[image]

*But how do they hide the reference from which line this code is fired?*

When I type `console.log` or any other function from the Console API there is always a reference link like `app.js:20` on the right end of line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools)

Comment: FYI, The reference is shown in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Quentin but that's only a basic explanation of how to disable/manipulate the console Object. I will try to fix that out based on that code and hopefully give an answer here.