# How to disable developer tools in webpage opened by selenium driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have created an application in selenium wherein it opens IE browser and enters user id and password by usind selenium's IE driver. However I want to prevent user from inspecting the auto data filled by selenium in the form. User can easily inspect the data using developer tools. So I want to know the way to disable developer tools options in selenium opened webpages.

Your help is highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook have done the same... [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools) ...so marking this as a duplicate question. P.S It's a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate an instance of `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions` then perform keystrokes for the F12 control.  This should toggle on/off the developer tools in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

I would also include a check to see if one of the controls from the devtools is there before toggling this, just to be sure that you don't turn them on instead of off.

c#:

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions actions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions([Instance of IWebDriver goes here]);
    actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F12).Perform();
```

Comment: But you can still open up Developer Tools through the browser menu.

Comment: .perform() will perform action however I want to disable developer tools option so he/she cant inspect page element.