# Fb share functionality not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I have created facebook share button functionality in wordpress.everithing works fine for me.
if any one other than me tries to share it produce following error message in console.

```
 .d8888b.  888                       888    
d88P  Y88b 888                       888    
Y88b.      888                       888    This is a browser feature intended for 
 "Y888b.   888888  .d88b.  88888b.   888    developers. If someone told you to copy-paste 
    "Y88b. 888    d88""88b 888 "88b  888    something here to enable a Facebook feature 
      "888 888    888  888 888  888  Y8P    or "hack" someone's account, it is a 
Y88b  d88P Y88b.  Y88..88P 888 d88P         scam and will give them access to your 
 "Y8888P"   "Y888  "Y88P"  88888P"   888    Facebook account.
                           888              
                           888              
                           888              

For more information, see https://www.facebook.com/selfxss.
```

can anyone tell me how to fix this

**edit**
my code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({appId: '1382611775340903', status: false, cookie: false, xfbml: false});
  };

  (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
     e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

`<a class="action_button" onclick="share(event)" href="javascript:void(0)" id="fb_share" target="_blank"> share this</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function share(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name:'<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>',
link: 'http://iseastest.juzzstaging.com/',
picture: '',
caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
message: ''
});
}
</script>                                                                                    screen shot![see screen shot][1]
```

Comment: Did you go to https://www.facebook.com/selfxss ?

Comment: yes.but there is no solution to fixit.

Comment: This is a warning we show everyone that opens the console on facebook.com, because there was an attack going around some time ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21692646/218196 . It should not have anything to do with your code. You might just not have implemented the sharing functionality correctly. Impossible to say without seeing your code.

Comment: And what exactly happens when you are trying to share?

Comment: showing an error has occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Status & Review` section of your facebook app, and see it's showing `Yes` for `Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?`. If not, you have to submit this app for review after filling mandatory informations under `App Details` section.

You should provide app `description`, `logo`, `contact email`.