# Prevent calls from the console of the browser Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

How can I prevent the client calling meteor calls directly from the console of the browser via developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. At least you can't do it in all browsers, so you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (it may help, but not sur that it will work on all browsers as Peppe LG says):

Client side code:

```
Object.defineProperty(console, '_commandLineAPI',
    { get : function() { throw 'Nooo!' } })
```

From: [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools)

Comment: As it says in the Epilogue in the answer you got your code from, it doesn't work in Chrome any more.