# How does Facebook log to console like this?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I was inspecting stuff, as you do, and came across this interesting thing on facebook.

[image: fb]
[<sup>`View Full Image`</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k6Is.png)

I understand that is completely do-able with something similar to this:

```
var cssRule =
    "color: rgb(249, 162, 34);" +
    "font-size: 60px;" +
    "font-weight: bold;" +
    "text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(249, 162, 34);" +
    "filter: dropshadow(color=rgb(249, 162, 34), offx=1, offy=1);";
console.log("%cHello World", cssRule);
```

<sup>[*Source*](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-styled-logging/)</sup>

My main question is, **How do they stop the showing of the file.js:line_numer** that you always get on the right hand side in console?

With the above code, you would see this:
[image: norm]
[<sup>`View Full Image`</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fym10.png)

Do you notice the red circle? But in facebooks example, they don't display that information. I've looked through the Web.Console API on Mozilla ([*Link*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)), so does anybody possibly know how to exclude that specific peice of information?

Comment: Maybe it is just hidden (also by CSS)?

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools?rq=1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just have to async/defer the `console.log` call, e.g.

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '%cFoo', 'color: #FF00FF;'), 0);
```

Comment: In FF, this makes the source display as `<unknown>`.

Comment: @Thilo OP's screenshots look like Chrome

Comment: If you just want a big message you can simplify by putting all the css in one line like @PaulS. , e.g.

console.log("%cHi from dnldr",  "font-size: 100px;" )

Answer (score 4):

Even though I joined the party late but I think this will do!

```
    var cssRule =
    "color: rgb(249, 162, 34);" +
    "font-size: 30px;" +
    "font-weight: bold;" +
    "text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(249, 162, 34);" +
    "filter: dropshadow(color=rgb(249, 162, 34), offx=1, offy=1);" setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, "%cHello World", cssRule), 0);
```