# Enable console.log when it is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, developer-tools, console.log

In a project, `console.log` is disabled. Firefox tells me it is disabled but I do not now where in the code and I do not want to look.

**Is there a way for me to force enable console.log around my code?**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript this might help you

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to disable it, are you using Firebug? you could try searching for console in about:config

Comment: read it maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools

Answer (score 4):

If **console.log()** is disabled with redefined function like

```
console.log = function() {}
```

You can try to delete it and browser will restore the default **console.log**

```
delete console.log
```

Comment: It seems; it does not work any more :(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to make "Firefox tells me it is disabled".

It is possible that someone replaced native browser "console.log" implementation.

To check what object is being referenced by "console.log" you should simply type it in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console and check out the result.
By default it should print "function()".

Comment: I can only guess that there is some problem with some Firefox addon.
I recommend you to try and run Firefox with all addons except Firebug disabled.