# How to edit console using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well I was actually looking to customize the console like what facebook does any guess. This is what facebook has. I wanna customize my console too please help!
[image]

Renote: The other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools) does not me the answer so no need of marking it as duplicate. It gives me the answer how did facebook freezed console not how did they brought up an error message got it @dfsq

Comment: Where do you see this? Not just on facebook.com right?