# Output HTML in Firebug / Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-plus, firebug

I was under the impression that you could only log text to the browser console with `console.log("text")` or `console.info("text")`, etc, how do these big websites manage to get different fonts and ascii art in the console?

Facebook on Chrome Console:

[image: chrome console showing html]

Google Plus on Chrome Console:

[image: chrome console showing html]

Facebook on Firebug Console:

[image: firebug showing ascii art]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools

Comment: Ah, so they completely override the console functionality. Well, in that case, I'm happy for this question to be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the console is not what allows them to use different colors.

It is a built in feature of `console.log()` that you can use by starting with `%c` to style text in the JavaScript Console with CSS properties.

Big red text:

```js
console.log("%cStop!", "font: 50px sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:red; -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;");
```

[image]

Red text on a yellow background:

```js
console.log("%cWARNING!", "font: 2em monospace; color: red; background-color: yellow;");
```

[image]

Ascii art:

```js
var asciiArt = [
  "",
  " .d8888b.  888                       888",
  "d88P  Y88b 888                       888",
  "Y88b.      888                       888",
  ' "Y888b.   888888  .d88b.  88888b.   888',
  '    "Y88b. 888    d88""88b 888 "88b  888',
  '      "888 888    888  888 888  888  Y8P',
  "Y88b  d88P Y88b.  Y88..88P 888 d88P",
  ' "Y8888P"   "Y888  "Y88P"  88888P"   888',
  "                           888",
  "                           888",
  "                           888",
];
var sideText = 'This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or "hack" someone\'s account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.';
var bottomText = "See https://www.facebook.com/selfxss for more information.";
// split lines in side text into groups of 35 characters until the end of a word
var split = ("" + sideText.toString()).match(/.{35}.+?\s+|.+$/g);
if (split != null) {
    // row of ascii text to start adding side text
    var startingRow = Math.floor(Math.max(0, (asciiArt.length - split.length) / 2));
    for (var i = 0; i < asciiArt.length || i < split.length; i++) {
        // add spaces and a line of sideText to each line of ascii art
        asciiArt[i] += new Array(45 - asciiArt[i].length).join(" ") + (split[i - startingRow] || "");
    }
}
// print ascii art followed by bottom text
console.log("\n\n\n" + asciiArt.join("\n") + "\n\n" + bottomText.toString() + "\n");
```