# How to hide source of Log messages in Console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When outputting messages into the console, the source is also displayed (in Chrome Developer Tools it's on the right):

```
console.log("Foo");                         //Source
Foo                               test.js:1 //Output
```

However, on some sites, messages are displayed *without* the source being displayed, such as on [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com):

[image: Console screenshot on Facebook.com]

Having a look on the [Chrome Console API Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api) there are examples across a ton of different outputs but all of them have the source displayed.

**How can I hide the source (`.js` page and line number) of console outputs?**

---

Edit: Just for clarification, this is not a duplicate of [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools) as that question answers how the console *disables* standard user input (and its answers explain how it works). I am specifically asking about the aesthetic of not displaying the source file and line.

Comment: Out of interest, on what URL do you see the console output you've shown in your image? I don't see that when I visit facebook.com in Chrome.

Comment: You must be logged in to see that message.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They are using `setTimeout` to detach from the source:

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '\n%c' + s[0], s[1]));
```

Comment: What does `s[0]` and `s[1]` reference? The message and the CSS style, I presume?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. 

But I am having a hard time to understand how it works. Can you explain how does it works?

Comment: @NirojShrestha Think of it like this: You're passing `setTimeout` a function, which is it supposed to execute later. So it places the function that was passed to it in a virtual space somewhere in memory and it loses the information of where it originated from. When the time comes, it will then execute that function, which has no line, because it just resides somewhere in memory. At least that's my take on things, I don't have a deep understanding of how the code is executed internally.

Comment: @DerHochstapler but why `setTimeout(() => console.log('hello world'));` show the trace?

Comment: @legend80s Because fat-arrow functions are different

Comment: @DerHochstapler Uh, so what's the difference?

Comment: why don't you just `setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, 'text'));`

Answer (score 4):

for those who are still looking for this, you can use something like

```js
function consoleWithNoSource(...params) {
  setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, ...params));
}

consoleWithNoSource("Helloo....!")
```