# How does setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, "something")) work?

Tags: javascript

After reading [How to hide source of Log messages in Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762774/how-to-hide-source-of-log-messages-in-console) , I'm confused about how this command works.

I try to not use setTimeout to wrap it, but the console log always show the source of log messages. Even I try to see the stack trace, it just shows nothing like the second line:
[image]

What does the `setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, "something"))` do?
And it seems cannnot remove setTimeout?

is there any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: I think we are not able to remove any error from console. Try console.clear()

Comment: @Ali I don't want to remove log messages, just want to know how it works. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take it piece-by-piece:

1. What is `console.log.bind(console, "something")`?

   The `Function#bind` function creates a new function that, when called, will call the original function using the first argument as `this` for the call and passing along any further arguments. So `console.log.bind(console, "something")` creates (but doesn't call) a function that, when it *is* called, will call `console.log` with `this` set to `console` and passing along `"something"` as the first argument.
2. What is `setTimeout(x, y)`?

   It schedules the function `x` to be called after `y` milliseconds by the browser; if you don't supply `y`, it defaults to `0` (call back immediately, as soon as the current code completes).

So taken together, `setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, "something"))` schedules a call to `console.log` after a brief delay.

Using the delay means that the call to `console.log` doesn't happen directly from the code where you do that; the browser calls `console.log` directly, not within your code. Consequently, the stack trace doesn't show that it happened in your code, because it didn't.

Comment: But why does `console.log` need to make `this` to `console`, what the differences between binding and without binding?

Comment: @North: On some (not all) browsers, if you call `console.log` with the wrong `this`, it fails. (Chrome, for instance.) Internally, apparently, the `console` object does use `this` to refer to its own properties, etc.