# Disable javascript execution from console

Tags: javascript, console

I've seen a lot of posts with this question. But apparently, they're all outdated. There's any chance to disable that execution nowadays?

EDIT: Chrome Console, I'm trying to deny any javascript execution that any user writes on the console.

Comment: Please elaborate, which javascript execution and what console?

Comment: are you trying to debug ?

Comment: using the dev tools in webkit / firebug you can always make minified code readable, set conditional breakpoints and override inner variables.

Comment: @zzzzBov Chrome Console, I'm trying to deny any javascript execution that any user writes on the console.

Comment: @edd2110, there's no way to do that. It's *their* console, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment:

> I'm trying to deny any javascript execution that any user writes on the console

This request is impossible. Users can execute whatever JavaScript they would like. They can also choose to disable any or all of your JavaScript.

Comment: It worth noting that it [was](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools) possible due to the bug in Chrome.