# How can I display a warning to users who open the Chrome console, like Facebook and Blockchain does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security

When I open the console on some sites like Facebook and Blockchain, I get a warning like the one below, I was wondering how I can do that on my site? Display a warning telling the user it's dangerous and he should not paste anything there.

[image]

Comment: It is just a console.log

Comment: They're just logging to the console, and they make sure not to have anything else in the log, just that message

Comment: Answer to this is explained better on following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can style console.log messages:

```
console.log('%cStop!', 'color: red; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `console.warn()` at `load` event of `window`.