# Code to display warning message when the console is activated?

Tags: javascript

[Self-XSS - History and mitigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS) states that

> Facebook and others now display a warning message when users open the
> web developer console

What is the HTML/Javascript code to display a warning message when the console is activated?

Comment: They just add console.log lines with styles. There is nothing special going on. I am sure if you use your favorite search engine with "facebook console.log stop message" you will get examples on how they do it.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165204/how-can-i-display-a-warning-to-users-who-open-the-chrome-console-like-facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Devtools Detect](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect) is a library that tells you if the console is open. After linking it in your html file, you could use the following code to print something when the console is open:

```js
window.addEventListener('devtoolschange', event => {
   if(event.detail.isOpen){
       console.log("Warning: Console is open");
   }
});
```