# Re-enable the console in Dev tools on facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-devtools

On facebook if you try to use the Console via Dev-tools it blocks you from entering anything.

This was well laid out here: [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Everywhere says this is not really a security feature for facebook but for their users. So that a general user doesn't get tricked and paste in malicious code given to them by "hackers" to gain access to their account.

I manage groups on facebook. And i want to execute javascript every once and a while to remove specific things or organize lists in specific ways... But i can not do this on facebook...

What is the solution? How do I execute commands in the console and disable their script blocking the use of the console? (I am not great with JavaScript but still would like to execute my basic commands)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use Tampermonkey or similar extension that runs userscripts instead. An alternative is to strip the anti-devtools hack in a MitM proxy like Fiddler.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! i am trying that now but no matter what i do i cant get a script to work on facebook using tampermonkey. I went and downloaded some other scripts for tampermonkey that were meant for facebook and those arent working either? Im not sure what im doing wrong...

Comment: You can add `debugger;` statement, open devtools, reload the page, and debug the scripts.

Comment: Oh i didnt realize i still got error messages in the console. Nice! Maybe it is working.. I just cant get it to work on facebook for some reason... Works fine in jsfiddle... :( Trying to filter out all friends from member lists in facebook groups

https://jsfiddle.net/et3hn3fk/