# Can one detect javascript code run inside console browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

The title sums up the question.

I am especially interested for Chrome 68+.

I have a website. I would like to know what code a user executes if he opens the chrome inspector and writes code.

Comment: Nope, not possible.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok, correct me if I'm wrong: If this was actually possible, there would be security concerns.

Comment: It *used* to be possible in Chrome, but it was patched in 2014.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693931/47589), but instead of throwing an error from `_commandLineAPI `, you instead just take note that a command was entered in the console.  This won't work anymore, though.

Answer (score 2):

## The answer is no.

It is impossible for the website to know what code was executed.

It may in many ways be able to detect the side-effects of code run in the console but knowing what was typed is not feasible.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and no because you have to use ctrl-shift-i to inspect in the browser, but that is still just inspecting.

Comment: You don't have to use Ctrl+Shift+I, you can open DevTools from the menu.