# Is it possible to attach listener or detect events fired on devtools / console in Chrome / FireFox web browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I would like to know if it is possible in modern browsers to add an event listener to devtools JS console, i.e. to attach onkeydown listener to get what keys were pressed in the browser's js console.

I want to disable users from typing anything in JS console on a page for some security reasons and I do not have control over server side so disabling or restricting users from manipulating page via browser console is one of the strongest option I have available at hand. The reason for this is to restrict them from accessing objects loaded by third party libraries. So far, I tried snippets from an old post described here [How does Facebook disable the browser's integrated Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools/21692733#21692733) in order to diable console at all but with no success. Any help or constructive criticism or critique is welcomed.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, the Chrome developers fixed the bug that Facebook was depending on. In general, browsers try hard to prevent you from doing what you're trying to do. If you discover a new way of doing it, they'll probably fix it.

Comment: You really should not depend on client-side security. There's no guarantee that your application will even be run from a real browser, someone could just download the code with `curl` or `wget` and craft responses by hand.

Comment: Hello @Barmar, Thank you for your reply. As I mentioned, I do not have any control over server side; so I am trying to tighten some loose ends on the client side.

Comment: I understand that, but you can't protect on the client side, since there might not even be a client.

Comment: So isn't this a duplicate? Even if you could block access to the JS console, there are ways to get around it with bookmarklets, user-scripts, and/or web-extensions.

Comment: @Kravimir, I do not think it is duplicate as my question here is to get information regarding possibility of attaching an event listener on devtools JavaScript console, which is not the issue of address in the link I posted above. ( at least I think so)