# Can we submit a form multiple times by writing a loop in console?

Tags: javascript, console

Actually in my application i have two input tags one is textarea and other is sort of button to submit it to the database. I want to ask how can I just write a loop in the console and submit the post to the database multiple times.  Is it really possible if it is then how can i prevent somebody to do it?

Comment: this is probably helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235872/how-to-disable-javascript-function-calls-from-the-browser-console

Comment: @imudin07 by the way is it even possible to submit it multiple times by just writing a loop in console?

Comment: If you don't prevent it, it is possible

Comment: I remember I tired to check my own project in this way, it worked

Comment: which line is it? you have one input tag, it should be [0]

Comment: No, actually I have two on the same page . The first one is for other purpose.

Comment: @imudin07    Without loop it worked fine but when I surround these two statements with a loop it just can't work

Comment: Where is your code? Can U show again?

Comment: @imudin07  `for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){ document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = "hattttttt"; document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].click(); }`The thing is when the loop done with its first iteration the page gets reloaded after submitting the post . That is why it is working only for one time.

Comment: @imudin07 Is there anything we can do to make it run for multiple times??

Comment: It depends on browsers, they don't allow for security risk

Comment: But I am curious about error

Comment: It is working here https://jsfiddle.net/411488ps/

Comment: Is it working at least once using loop?

Comment: @imudin07 yes it is working only once.

Comment: Then don't reload the page, try to use ajax request

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, you can submit. There is an example:

```
<div id='post'></div>
<input type=button>
<input type=button onclick="test()">

<script>
  function test() {
    $.get('https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!', function(data) {
      document.getElementById("post").innerHTML += data;
    });
  }

</script>
```

Try to call `test()` function in loop or 
`for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){ document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].click(); }` 
in browser console and check network, you can see multiple requests and `post` div is updated

https://jsfiddle.net/411488ps/3/

If you want to prevent it, you have to do something in server side.
You can't trust anything sent to the server from the client. You must implement checks at the server end to rate-limit (or just limit), validate, etc., because people can send you any information they like (they don't even have to be using a web browser to do it).
Also check this http://www.queness.com/post/16151/disable-javascript-console-in-browsers